# Issue while ajax request in MVC5

Tags: .net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm facing a very strange issue while applying ajax request in my mvc5 project. Here is my code in Index.cshtml:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
 for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "Home/LoadTodayStories",
            data: { pageIndex: blockNumber, pageSize: 8, index: i }, 
            dataType: 'html',
            async: false,
            beforeSend: function () { $("#loadingDiv").show(); },
            complete: function () { $('#loadingDiv').hide(); },
            success: function (data) {
                $('.today-spl').append(data);
            },
            error: function (e) { alert(e.responseText); }
        });
    }
});
```

this code works perfectly when I just run my project and there is no whole url including the controller name and action method. In other words if the url is just "http://localhost:52572/" the code works, however when I include controller name and action method such as "http://localhost:52572/Home/Index" I got error saying:

> The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /Home/Home/LoadTodayStories

P.S. I know what the error is and I need to change my ajax request url part from

```
url: "Home/LoadTodayStories",
```

to

```
 url: "LoadTodayStories",
```

But after changing this part, the code starts working with url "http://localhost:52572/Home/Index" and does not work with "http://localhost:52572/". Does anyone have idea how to get this work with both the conditions?

My RouteConfig.cs:

```
 routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: show your route configuration.

Comment: @Ric please see my edited question

Comment: have you tried setting the `contentType` to`contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` ? Also show your method for `LoadTodayStories`

Comment: @Ric how would that supposed to be affect the code? Content type just indicates which type of data you're sending to the server for ajax request.

Comment: I believe the default content type is not `application/json` http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ and you are sending `json`

Comment: btw I've tried adding content type but no luck...

Comment: Show the signature for the method `LoadTodayStories`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91083/discussion-between-shilpa-soni-and-ric).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard coded urls always gave me issues and are a bad idea anyway. I always use url helpers.

```
 url: "@Url.Action("LoadTodayStories","Home")"
```

If this is in a separate javascript file where html helpers are unavailable, just add a hidden field to your view:

```
<input type="hidden" id="loadTodayStoriesUrl" value="@Url.Action("LoadTodayStories", "Home")" />
```

Then in your javascript, get the generated url from the hidden:

```
url: $('#loadTodayStoriesUrl').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always include controller and action names in your urls. But keep in mind that it all depends your routing configuration - you can remap specific controller and action to a different url.
You can take a look here: http://stephenwalther.com/archive/2015/02/07/asp-net-5-deep-dive-routing